# how to assign value to a specific field in a database using php?

Tags: php

i am having  a hard time to assign the value of $temp (an int variable) to a field in database by using php. how am i going to assign the value of $temp to field fldvote_count where fldname ='exec1_1' in table tblexec_votes? please help me, this is my code, it is not working, the database does not update using this. thank you.

```
$result="UPDATE tblexec_votes SET fldvote_count= '$temp' WHERE fldname ='exec1_1'";
```

Answer (score 1):

change to:

```
$result="UPDATE tblexec_votes SET fldvote_count= '".mysql_real_escape_string($temp)."' WHERE fldname ='exec1_1'";
```

Comment: what var_dump($temp) return?

Answer (score 0):

It's `$temp` and not `&temp`!

```
$result="UPDATE tblexec_votes SET fldvote_count= '$temp' WHERE fldname ='exec1_1'";
```

By the way, **don't** do this if you don't really need to! Use prepared statements.